# angular.js get slash-separated path from url

Tags: angularjs

I need to take as a parameter in my site's urls a file path (that will contain some number of '/' characters). How can I parse such a parameter from a url? Something like `http://localhost/path/to/file` would be preferable, but if that doesn't work, `http://localhost/?path=/path/to/file` or something could work as well.

Comment: The former must be handled by your server using url rewrite rules. The latter can be done with the [`$location`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location) service.

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller How exactly are you supposed to use `$location`? I added it as a parameter to my controller and am printing `$location.url()` (via a function) in my view, but all I get is the empty string (when accessing, eg, `http://localhost:8000/?path=lol`)

Comment: Same for `$location.search()`, just gives me an empty object as output.

Comment: To access your `path` param using $location: `$location.search().path`.

Comment: Like I said, `$location.search()` is an empty object for me when accessing `http://localhost:8000/?path=lol`. Is there anything I need to do other than have `$location` as a parameter to my controller to get it to work?

Comment: Should work. You'll have to post a plunker.

Comment: http://pastie.org/6517877 The `stuff: {{ loc() | json }}` at the bottom always just appears as `stuff: {}`

Comment: I get the same thing, and when I log $location, I get `{"$$protocol":"http","$$host":"localhost","$$port":5000,"$$path":"","$$search":{},"$$hash":"","$$url":"","$$absUrl":"http://localhost:5000/login.html?error=true"}`. Clearly it's parsing the URL, but why are the `url` and `search` parameters empty?

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227004/how-to-capture-urls-with-arbitrary-number-of-slashes-in-angular-js) for essentially the same thing, but there the path part comes in the *angular* part of the URL, after the hash, so webserver-side rewrites should technically not be necessary.

Comment: @nh2 That question doesn't have an answer, I provided a work around for the general idea but as far as I can tell you can't have an arbitrary number of slashes in the angular url.

Answer (score 0):

to use location in your controller. first turn html5mode to true like this

Then you can use
location.search and it will return string without any error.
for more use of location go here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: How to turn html5mode on

Comment: angular.module("MyAPP",[],function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [URI.js](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/), it looks like what you need.