# How to capture URLs with arbitrary number of slashes in angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

I want to make an angular site dealing with files where users can navigate around in a file system tree, (like on github: `github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/path/to/my/file.js`.

I would like to capture that `path/to/my/file.js` part of the URL with an angular route:

```
.when("/files/:myPath", templateUrl: "...", controller: "...")
```

but as expected, `:myPath` only matches up to the next slash.

How can I capture *all remaining parts* of the URL, including an arbitrary number of slashes?

---

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426226/angular-js-get-slash-separated-path-from-url) that is related, but differs in that my URL is fine to be after the angular hash, e.g. `.../index.html#/files/path/to/my/file`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of Angular 1.1.5 you can use `*path` - see [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.$routeProvider).

> path can contain named groups starting with a star (***name**). All characters are eagerly stored in
> `$routeParams` under the given name when the route matches.
>
> For example, routes like **/color/:color/largecode/*largecode/edit** will match
> **/color/brown/largecode/code/with/slashs/edit**

As of Angular 1.3, the syntax is `:path*` (credit to DRAX in the comments)

Comment: The catch-all was introduced at 1.1.3, but it's all the same, it is only available in the unstable branch. Nice catch @tungd, I didn't know this until now!

Comment: That sounds like it's exactly what I asked for!

Comment: I would like just to make an update for Angular 1.3. You should use :largecode* instead of *largecode